# Overlapping TextInputs in Kivy using FloatLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, textinput

Using this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout(size=(100, 100))
        root.add_widget(TextInput(pos=(0, 0)))
        root.add_widget(TextInput(pos=(50, 50)))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

I get two `TextInput`s, one on top of the other. When I click on the top `TextInput` (by clicking somewhere in the middle of the screen), the focus goes to the lower `TextInput` for some reason. In fact, the only way I can get focus on the top `TextInput` is by clicking entirely outside of the lower `TextInput` (by clicking right at the top of the screen). Why does this happen, and how can I circumvent this?

Comment: Ref [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5092).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be approached in two ways.[Float layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html) honors the pos_hint and the size_hint properties of its children.So you need to set size_hint for textinput.

ie-

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout(size=(100, 100))
        root.add_widget(TextInput(pos=(0, 0),size_hint=(0.5,0.5)))
        root.add_widget(TextInput(pos=(100, 100),size_hint=(0.5,0.5)))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

or use boxlayout instead of floatlayout

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout(size=(100, 100))
        root.add_widget(TextInput(pos=(0, 0)))
        root.add_widget(TextInput(pos=(50, 50)))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Comment: Neither approach works for me. Using `size_hint` just resizes the `TextInput` widgets and doesn't change the way the focus is handled in the overlapping regions. `BoxLayout` just moves one `TextInput` to the side of the other (i.e., no overlapping).

Comment: Ok i see.I misunderstood the problem.Yr concern is genuine and i feel like it is a bug.To work around you could give a try with `focus = True` for first widget and `focus = False` for second and change it dynamically for reverse like `focus = False` for first widget and `focus = True` for second widget.You can do it with onclick method.